# Created a remove function for a list in javascript but it is not removing elements

Tags: javascript

I'm going through Data Structures and Algos by O'Reily and I'm on page 54 where I've already written out my list function and I'm testing out my append and remove functions. My remove function won't actually work and I used what is in the book. Here is the function:

```
function remove(element)
{
    var foundAt = this.find(element);
    if (foundAt > -1)
    {
        // splice(index, howmany, item1, ...., itemX)
        this.dataStore.splice(foundAt, 1);
        --this.listSize;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

When I try to run

```
names.remove("Raymond");
```

like in the book, "Raymond" is not removed from the list. Not sure what I could be wrong. Here is my code:

```js
    function List() {
      this.listSize = 0;
      this.pos = 0;
      this.dataStore = []; //initializes an empty array to store list     elements
      //this.clear = clear;
      this.find = find;
      this.toString = toString;
      //this.insert = insert;
      this.append = append;
      this.remove = remove;
      //this.front = front;
      //this.end = end;
      //this.prev = prev;
      //this.next = next;
      this.length = length;
      //this.currPost = currPos;
      //this.moveTo = moveTo;
      //this.getElement = getElement;
      this.length = length;
      //this.contains = contains;
    }

     // append an element
    function append(element) {
      this.dataStore[this.listSize++] = element;
    }

     // remove an element
    function find(element) {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.dataStore; ++i) {
        if (this.dataStore[i] == element) {
          return i;
        }
      }
      return -1;
    }

     // after the array is modified
     // listSize is decremented by 1 to reflect the size of the list
    function remove(element) {
      var foundAt = this.find(element);
      if (foundAt > -1) {
        // splice(index, howmany, item1, ...., itemX)
        this.dataStore.splice(foundAt, 1);
        --this.listSize;
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }

    function length() {
      return this.listSize;
    }

    function toString() {
      return this.dataStore;
    }

    var names = new List();
    names.append("Cynthia");
    names.append("Raymond");
    names.append("Barbara");
    console.log(names.toString());
    names.remove("Raymond");
    console.log(names.toString());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing's being removed because your `find` method's loop is wrong.

**Change**:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.dataStore; ++i)
```

**To**:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.dataStore.length; ++i)
```

**Fixed**:
https://jsfiddle.net/vjd7zocd/

Comment: Thanks! I kept looking over that I guess :(